# Database Table Structure for a simple RPG

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

I'm currently practising on SQLite and making a simple text based RPG, but I need some advice with table structure.

So far I've come up with a **"Player"** table which stores the Player information.
An **"Inventory"** table, connected to its "Player" ID.
An **"Item"** table that holds all the Items.

Here is my issue. I have a **"Weapon"** model, **"Shield"**, **"Chest"**, **"Legs"** etc. etc. for each Item-type equipment, which holds maybe 50-100 items each. Should I store ALL items in a long list of **"Item"** table or should I make Sub-Tables? Like a "Weapon" table, a "Shield" table etc. and remove the "Item" table?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer should be to follow recognised realtional database design guidelines which would very much depend upon the full functionality requirements of the game.

However, I'd suggest that the resolution would be neither just a list of items nor just separate tables for item types. Rather a table for items which has a column for the **"type"** which references tables (Weapon, Armour, collectables(etc)) and perhaps a **type** table.

Say for example a Weapon had a force value (how hard it hits) and a speed value (how frequently it hits), but armour only has a defence value and collectables had a weight value. The item list could be quite a complicated affair i.e. in this simple scenario that's 4 additional columns, with quite a bit of redundancy i.e. collectables and armour only utilise 25%, whilst 50% for a weapon, so perhaps you could introduce more complicated processing to utilise just 2 columns.

SQLite wise perhaps the tables could be :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rpg_player (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, player_name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rpg_item(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, type_reference INTEGER, item_subtype_reference INTEGER, UNIQUE(type_reference,item_subtype_reference));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rpg_inventory(player_id INTEGER, item_id INTEGER, number_held INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(player_id, item_id)) WITHOUT ROWID;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rpg_item_types(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, type_name TEXT, type_flags INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rpg_weapon(weapon_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, weapon_name TEXT, weapon_flags INTEGER, weapon_force INTEGER, weapon_speed INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rpg_armour(armour_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, armour_name TEXT, armour_flags INTEGER, armour_defence INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rpg_collectable(collectable_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, collectable_name TEXT, collectable_flags INTEGER, collectable_weight INTEGER);
```

These say are populated as :-

#### Player Table

[image: Player Table]

#### Item Table

The master Item table catering for all items to be easily referenced. (*e.g. in the inventory*). An entry has it's own unqiue id that references the type (weapon, armour.....) and then the item within the sub type table:-

- The first row has a unique id of **1,** (1st column) the item is of type **2**(2nd column) (id 2 in the **rpg_item_types** table)  (**Armour**) and is the item of armour that has an id of **5** (3rd column) in the **rpg_armour** table (**Arm Thinggies**).
- Likewise item 3 is a Weapon (column 1 is 1, so type 1) that being the weapon that has an id in the weapon table of 2 (**Great Sword**).

[image: Item Table (just references to other tables)]

- Only references other tables but all items have a unique id
- `type_reference` is the type whilst `item_subtype_reference` is the `id` of the item in that respective type table (weapon, armour, collecatble).
- A table **Constraint** is set so that a combination of type_reference and item_subtype_reference must be unique as per `UNIQUE(type_reference,item_subtype_reference)`

#### Inventory Table

[image: Inventory Table]

#### Item Types

This table has an entry for each subclass of items.
[image: Item Types Table]

#### Sub Item Tables

Tables that model the specifics of the item e.g. rpg_weapon has a weapon_force and weapon_speed column, whilst rpg_armour only has an armour_defence column
[image: Weapon Table]
[image: Armour]
[image: Collectable]

---

You could create a simple list (output wise) of the Items using the following :-

```
--LIST ALL ITEMS
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN type_name = 'Weapon' THEN weapon_name || ' Type (' || type_name || ')'
        WHEN type_name = 'Armour' THEN armour_name || ' Type (' || type_name || ')'
        WHEN type_name = 'Collectable' THEN collectable_name || ' Type (' || type_name || ')'
    END AS description
    FROM rpg_item
    JOIN rpg_item_types ON type_reference = rpg_item_types._id
    LEFT JOIN rpg_weapon ON item_subtype_reference = weapon_id
    LEFT JOIN rpg_armour ON item_subtype_reference = armour_id
    LEFT JOIN rpg_collectable ON item_subtype_reference = collectable_id
```

Resulting in :-

[image]

The following would list the all inventory items :-

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN rpg_item.type_reference = 1 THEN 'Player - ' || player_name || ' has ' || weapon_name || ' it is a ' || type_name || ' it has a force of ' || weapon_force
        WHEN rpg_item_types.type_name = 'Armour' THEN  'Player - ' || player_name || ' has ' || armour_name || ' it is a ' || type_name || ' with a defence rating of ' || armour_defence
        WHEN rpg_item.type_reference = 3 THEN 'Player - ' || player_name || ' has ' || collectable_name || ' it is a ' || type_name || ' it has a weight of ' || collectable_weight
    END AS description
    FROM rpg_inventory
    JOIN rpg_player ON player_id = rpg_player._id
    JOIN rpg_item ON rpg_inventory.item_id = rpg_item._id
    JOIN rpg_item_types ON rpg_item.type_reference = rpg_item_types._id
    LEFT JOIN rpg_weapon ON rpg_item.item_subtype_reference = rpg_weapon.weapon_id
    LEFT JOIN rpg_armour ON rpg_item.item_subtype_reference = rpg_armour.armour_id
    LEFT JOIN rpg_collectable ON rpg_item.item_subtype_reference =rpg_collectable.collectable_id
```

The result based upon the above (ooops no weapons held by anyone) :-

[image]

A simple `WHERE` clause (`WHERE player_id = ?`) would restrict the list to a single player.

- e.g. `WHERE player_id = 2` would only list Fredrica's inventory.

You may well want to copy and paste the above and use it in an SQLite tool, there's quite a few around (I'm personally quite happy with SQLite Manager, other's would recommend other tools, all of the above was done using such a tool). There's probably quite a good chance that you could create the core Database access functionality just using such a tool.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you :)